# How to write features in nltk to a txt file?

Tags: python, file, machine-learning, stdout, nltk

I trained a naive bayes classifier with nltk. The function `show_most_informative_features` ([source code](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/master/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py)) can print out the top likelihood features in the training process to python shell, but it has no return value.

[image]

And now I want to write the most informative features into a txt file. However the features are all Unicode, containing Chinese/Japanese words and some special notations. I was not able to use '>' to redirect the print to a txt file.

So how can I write the features to a txt file using this function without return value? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple changed from source code. (I'm not try.)

```
def show_most_informative_features(self, n=10):
    strlist = []
    # Determine the most relevant features, and display them.
    cpdist = self._feature_probdist
    # print('Most Informative Features')
    strlist.append('Most Informative Features')

    for (fname, fval) in self.most_informative_features(n):
            def labelprob(l):
                return cpdist[l,fname].prob(fval)
            labels = sorted([l for l in self._labels
                     if fval in cpdist[l,fname].samples()],
                    key=labelprob)
            if len(labels) == 1: continue
            l0 = labels[0]
            l1 = labels[-1]
            if cpdist[l0,fname].prob(fval) == 0:
                ratio = 'INF'
            else:
                ratio = '%8.1f' % (cpdist[l1,fname].prob(fval) /
                          cpdist[l0,fname].prob(fval))
            # print(('%24s = %-14r %6s : %-6s = %s : 1.0' %
            #      (fname, fval, ("%s" % l1)[:6], ("%s" % l0)[:6], ratio)))
            strlist.append(('%24s = %-14r %6s : %-6s = %s : 1.0' %
                          (fname, fval, ("%s" % l1)[:6], ("%s" % l0)[:6], ratio)))

    return strlist

# Useage
list = show_most_informative_features(classifier, 100)
file.writelines(list)
```

P.S.

Please do not direct change at source code!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just stuck in “print” the results to a txt file, forgot to change the source code. And this method works well!

Comment: Please do not change the source code of the nltk library! This is really bad practice. What would happen if you update the library for instance, or if you need to share your code with someone else who hasn't modified its library accordingly ?

Comment: Thanks, I mean copy code from source code and change. not change at source code.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not change the source code of the nltk library!
This is really bad practice. What would happen if you update the library for instance, or if you need to share your code with someone else who hasn't modified its library accordingly ?

The behaviour of libraries is standardized for reasons !

For your question, you have the equivalent function

```
classifier.most_informative_features(n)
```

which return a list of the n most informative features of the classifier you trained !!!!

Comment: Yes, anyone needing a list of most informative features for naive bayes should be using this answer. Unfortunately, maxent doesn't have an equivalent method.